# how do you handle do not repeat yourself gherkin script?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests, dry

I am new to Cucumber and Gherkin, here's the situation I think I will come across. A home page contains many features, naturally you want to start from the home and perform a task, feature.

```
Given user logged into home page
When user performs feature 1
Then ... 

Given user logged into home page
When user performs feature 2
Then ...
```

When you run Cucumber the for the second feature, it will complain that the Given step is ambiguous.

How does one resolve this issue? You can change the Given step a little bit for the second  feature. By doing so, you are actually repeating yourself. Thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

if user logged into homepage is a pre requisite for your tests within the feature to run, then put it in the background:

```
Background:
  Given user logged into home page
```

Then:

```
Scenario: 1
When user performs feature 1
Then ... 

Scenario: 2
When user performs feature 2
Then ...
```

Comment: I think I would have to put everything into one file.  I don't really know how to refactor the situation. Think of it as logging into eBay. You can sell, bid, watch and buy.  They all logged into the same home page.

Comment: I never had this problem, Cucumber (in my experience) looks for all steps in your steps file so define it once in one file only and use it in as many features as you want.

Comment: I see what you mean... you dont need to add the login implementation twice... you add it once in 1 step definition file and reuse it across your features...

Comment: One thing to note: when defining steps used in multiple tests make sure you keep them in a generic step definition file rather than in the step definition file for the first test to use them. Otherwise it will turn into a rather painful search when you decide to change the step implementation at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I set mine up slightly different, taking your example

```
Given user logged into home page
When user performs feature 1
Then ... 

Given user logged into home page
When user performs feature 2
Then ...
```

Within my corresponding steps file i would just have a section at the top for reusable steps (as don't forget all matches are on regexp)

```
# Reusable Steps
Given(/^user logged into home page$/) do
  # login steps here
end

# Feature 1
When(/^user performs feature 1$/) do
  # steps here
end

# Feature 2
When(/^user performs feature 2$/) do
  # steps here
end
```

personal preference i guess but thought i would share